# Android dialog transparency (not the usual)

Tags: android

I have an issue with my android dialog. I would like it to be displayed over any activity (probably a no-no as far as design guidelines but I have good reason). This works. And I'm %95 happy with it. The issue is there seems to be an activity background still displayed beneath my dialog.  This is apparent if I don't call finish() on my activity on each intended close action. Which I've done so it's less problematic, however, the dialog closes a split second prior to the activity background being cleared so the user sees an ugly centimeter long box for a split second as it finishes.

[***_*___**]

Is there any way to combat this? I've tried all of the API dialog themes: No action bar, no title bar, transparent, etc etc to no avail. I also attempted to set the dialog color to full transparency as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Design guidelines can be cool with your dialog, many apps use a dialog for confirmation, inputting a small text, etc... It really depends if it feels natural or not. But I don't understand your question very well. You mean, you need to kill both things at once, the dialog and its parent activity? Kind of a "close application" dialog? It would help if you add a screen shot.

Comment: Oh wow sorry I forgot I ever posted this. And yes, sort of. I can't screenshot it fast enough to do so haha. But the parent activity IS the dialog's that is closing directly at the same time as the dialog and is still visible as a small box due to this for a split second during the close. Basic action is: dialog closes - activity box is visible for a split second at the direct center of where the dialog was - closes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    this.finish();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Be very careful with that! You are altering the application lifecycle in a dangerous way! Mind that the onPause method can be called in a variety of situations, even without you being aware (for example, rotating the tablet/phone), causing your activity to be killed. I even predict you can cause a variety of nasty side-effects, because you are triggering a finish (onStop-onDestroy) when the activity requests a Pause, which you capture and transform into a Finish. When finish call ends, you go back and trigger a pause.... total mess!

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. I had the same problem but was an dialog activity.This is alerDialog?

Comment: Oh wow sorry I forgot I ever posted this. The parent activity IS the dialog's that is closing directly at the same time as the dialog and is still visible as a small box due to this for a split second during the close. Basic action is: dialog closes - activity box is visible for a split second at the direct center of where the dialog was - closes. And the dialog type doesn't matter in this case it's just closing the activity behind the dialog rather than before the dialog which I realize is how it would work, but the visible activity box for that split second is the issue.